# The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. "in my production hosting cpanel after i login" laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the following error when I login with username and password:

[image]
I've tried:

```
cache:clear 
route:clear 
view:clear 
config:clear
```

but it not working

Comment: Please can you show the code for your form. Also, is this error happening after a refresh?

Comment: try running `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan optimize
```

When you clear you cache you have to config it as well. `Optimize` command will do that for you (also clear your routes,files etc etc all in 1), or `php artisan config:cache` after clear

But that issue could come from your form itself. Make sure in your form you have this field inside :

```
<form method="POST" action="/myPage">
    @csrf

// html goes here.
</form
```